# Jpcap crashes when trying to open device

Tags: java, packet-capture, jpcap

I use Jpcap in order to create ARP requests but when calling the method `JpcapCaptor.openDevice(interface,snaplen,promisc,to_ms);`, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setPacketValue
  at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.nativeOpenLive(Native Method)
  at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.openDevice(JpcapCaptor.java:61)
```

The jpcap dll file I'm using was compiled from the source in order to work on Windows 64 bits. Is there anyway I can solve that weird problem ?

After having looked in the jpcap.dll file source code, I see that the following code is used in the openDevice method (the one that crashes) of the JpcapCaptor.java file:

```
JpcapCaptor jpcap = new JpcapCaptor();
String ret = jpcap.nativeOpenLive(intrface.name, snaplen, (promisc ? 1 : 0), to_ms);
```

According to the compiler, this is the second line of this piece of code that crashes. So I looked in the nativeOpenLive method which comes from the file JpcapCaptor.c which starts with:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_jpcap_JpcapCaptor_nativeOpenLive(JNIEnv *env,jobject obj,jstring device,jint snaplen,jint promisc,jint to_ms){
char *dev;
jint id;
set_Java_env(env);
```

However, in this last function (set_Java_env), I found the call to the setPacketValue method in the following form: `setPacketValueMID=(*env)->GetMethodID(env,Packet,"setPacketValue","(JJII)V");`

Having only very weak bases in C, I would like to know the meaning of these different methods and, if possible, where the error comes from.

**The source is available at the following address: https://github.com/jovigb/jpcap-x64/blob/master/src**